# How to get a string dump of an executable in PHP?

Tags: php, regex, string, hex, dump

I'm working on a project in PHP, and i need to get a list of all strings contained in a executable PE file, like some desktop programs do. Here is a screenshot of what i need that the file returns:

> [image]

I can have the HEX dump of the file, and the strings are there, but i don't know how to extract them. Maybe with regex, idk...

I could make a program in C that return the strings to the PHP script, but i want to make it using PHP, because i'll upload the script to a host, and maybe i cannot use commandline or something like this.

Any tips about this?

Comment: Did you look at : http://php.net/manual/en/function.bin2hex.php ?  Why do you think you can't use commandline commands within php?

Comment: Yes, as i said, i have the hex dump of the file, but i don't know how to extrack the strings from there... And i don't know if i could use command line commands because i'll upload the script to my linux host, and the host blocks the system() function for security reasons.